# Spfx react web part property pane changes reflect in other three column section web part in modern page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I have created one react spfx web part which get data from selected SharePoint list and render the data on modern page.

But when I added web part in three column section at that time when I changes first section web part property pane it also reflect other section web part also.

Is there any way to stop applying one section web part property changes to another section web part ?

Comment: Are you using same SPFx web part with different configurations 3 times on same page? Are you updating the property pane values based on DOM element id/classes etc.? Make sure to use the unique id/classes for property pane elements and test again.